# Complete list of options for .inputrc / readline

Tags: readline, inputrc

I always knew you could switch between Vim and Emacs bindings for Bash by modifying `.inputrc`.

I'm now realizing there are actually a few different useful options I've decided to turn on including:

```
set bell-style none
set colored-stats On
set show-all-if-ambiguous On
```

The comments in `/etc/inputrc` on my system provide some guidance as to what is possible but not all the options are shown there.

I'm also trying `man readline` but all I get is a really short page describing the program.

Is there somewhere I can see all the options which can be turned on and off via `.inputrc`?

Comment: Readline options are listed inside `man bash`.

Comment: I get a really long man page with `man 3 readline`  you many need to install some dev package to get this section 3 page.

Comment: there's also a readline-doc package in debian

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check the `bind` [Bash builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

Use `help bind` to see the different options.

In particular, you could check the output of

- `bind -l` : List names of functions.
- `bind -p` : List functions and bindings in a form that can be reused as input.
- `bind -v` : List variable names and values in a form that can be reused as input.

Answer (score 0):

not certain it's complete, but the [Archlinux page for readline(3)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/readline.3) provides a fairly comprehensive list of options.

In addition to that there's the [The GNU Readline Library documentation](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) page which has a good deal on the syntax and commands.  Again, hard to tell if it's comprehensive.